# how do i link to pdf file in drupal 7

Tags: files

I have a content type in which i created flie type field and text type field.I uploaded the pdf file and wrote 'link' to text field.
I have copied the link from uploaded file and with the use of ckeditor given the link to the text 'link'. Now when i click to text 'link' then the pdf file get opened. But the problem is if we look at the url it says 'www.example.com/sites/default/files/ADMISSION_FORM.pdf'. which is not correct and secured i think. it shud be somelike 'www.example.com/node/35/ADMISSION_FORM.pdf'.
  Can anyone who knows tell me the fact....??????Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That's not a problem, Drupal stores uploaded files under sites/default/files by default. There's no reason file paths for uploaded files would be similar to the URL of the node they're attached to.

www.example.com/sites/default/files/ADMISSION_FORM.pdf is the correct path if you haven't changed any of the default settings. I'm not sure why you've mentioned security, as that really doesn't come into it.